# Eisenstein's criterion for two variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I want to know if there is a criterion, like Eisenstein's criterion, for polynomials with 2 variables? 
If there is, how does it work?

Comment: Notice that if $A$ is a factorial ring, then $A[X,Y]=B[Y]$ where $B=A[X]$ is factorial, so that you can apply Eisenstein criterion on $B[Y]$.